# Conditional interface on parameter type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make a typescript function with a conditional return type.
My function need to accept 2 types : `BotLotteryPrize[]` and `Lot[]` and return `BotLotteryPrize` or `Lot` accordingly.

### Interfaces

**BotLotteryPrize**:

```js
export type BotLotteryPrize = {
  id: string
  videoUrl: string | null
  probabilityToWin: number
  ...
}
```

**Lot**:

```js
export type Lot = {
  id: string
  probabilityToWin: number
  credit: number | null
  ...
}
```

So I tried to write that :

```
type BotLotteryPrizeOrLot<T extends (BotLotteryPrize | Lot)[]> =
  T extends BotLotteryPrize[] ? BotLotteryPrize : Lot;
```

```js
function raffleDrawWithDistribution<T extends Array<BotLotteryPrize | Lot>>(
  items: T,
): BotLotteryPrizeOrLot<T> {
  const randomInt = this.generateRandomInt();

  const sumOfProbabilities = items.reduce(
    (acc, currentItem) => acc + currentItem.probabilityToWin,
    0,
  );

  if (sumOfProbabilities !== 1) {
    items.forEach((item) => {
      item.probabilityToWin = item.probabilityToWin / sumOfProbabilities;
    });
  }

  const probabilities = items.reduce(
    (acc, currentLot, idx) => {
      const nextProbability = acc[idx] + currentLot.probabilityToWin;
      return [...acc, nextProbability];
    },
    [0],
  );

  let wonItem: Lot | BotLotteryPrize = null;

  items.forEach((item, idx) => {
    if (randomInt > probabilities[idx] && randomInt <= probabilities[idx + 1]) {
      wonItem = item;
    }
  });

  return wonItem;
}
```

### Problematic

At the return of my function I get a ts error :

```
Type 'BotLotteryPrize | Lot' is not assignable to type 'BotLotteryPrizeOrLot<T>'.
  Type 'BotLotteryPrize' is not assignable to type 'BotLotteryPrizeOrLot<T>
```

Comment: Try some [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all this type:

```
type BotLotteryPrizeOrLot<T extends (BotLotteryPrize | Lot)[]> =
  T extends BotLotteryPrize[] ? BotLotteryPrize : Lot;
```

Is kind of silly. It basically simplifies to:

```
type BotLotteryPrizeOrLot<T extends (BotLotteryPrize | Lot)[]> = T[number]
```

And conditional types are notoriously difficult to assign to so this is a big improvement. It's also so simple you don't need it at all.

---

I say, change your function to this:

```
function raffleDrawWithDistribution<T extends BotLotteryPrize | Lot>(
  items: T[],
): T {
  //...
}
```

And then just let `items` infer the type for you. Calling `items.find` will return a `T | undefined` so you don't have to mess with it.

```
const wonItem = items.find((item, idx) => {
  return randomInt > probabilities[idx] && randomInt <= probabilities[idx + 1]
})

if (!wonItem) throw new Error("Failed to win an item!")

return wonItem;
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBCEYBlM2FRABSgEsAvVAXjgG8AoOOEgEwC44BnGUgOwHMGcAG4tgEAKpQANuy68+cAD5weAVylTBYKBABGAQ10kpJJABUIAdRI92agLa78dAL506oSLATJUOeNT0jCyy3DYCjNp6hsamiBbWtiqqjs6MAMZQwMymdilOUErJGq7uAGaqPOkwJBA8cFD6ZWVSwAAijQDu1jAAFm0kciS6qjV1ADxmcKB4PMwc6Jj+eATE5KjK-gB8ABSCpsD2HOxmANoAugA0dACUJ7SC6XVcDfpzEPYAkjwBcACy+j6ADpGu97DsbgBuOAAehhnE6+jAKGYCF6gwQEDgfGA8DeiGSqUKQn0UlUwHcGWe8A4KQA8mViNEjCYasAFtQDkcQdlVOlgHtGIwdvp0ulLnB0qooFkfp88PYbnBKFs4KL0nAANSS6WymDyw5AqIGFlxBI2a5CuAABktcChlKYZTgO1p9gZTJNsTZCwAhJRqABGJVBIVcjhAsrQACiot6Ox2XKVKoeVuCCqNOi9rPiVhsyqYGeNMRz5vq8LdHqzJdMJHZkMEjBcDqbjqePBexdNPoL4Z5zD5AsbLvVEqlMuAP38EpYIGTqtDVvbLx4M09NaQBfVp1n5y1OonU8wmeZ3tziQbaYauOl9VOQIfo5Ua+r3cQ50vQpcdsYp2tV0EB1HmpOBOjqA17F7BUIzKGxmATLkZ2YOdlQXYcshgW9XjBb54FVLtvTrDgd2QvcADIyOw5gPlwuBxmoAjWSIkiQH3QNzkEZtHRIZ0dl9MCeAgpU+h0TpnzE6MZWgHYACIADF9GMbJMVA-M3kLQ5fRkm5HQwrCBIghs3CAA)

Comment: Perfect this solution is working. But I think the BotLotteryPrizeOrLot type  is no longer useful